# Java5 FileInputStream fails before I can get file lock

Tags: java, nio, file-locking

I have application (Java5) distributed among several JVMs that reads/writes files from a shared storage (the storage is managed by Windows). I wanted to use exclusive/shared locks for file write/read as following:

```
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    FileLock lock = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("//share/test.dat"));  // HERE IT MAY THROW FileNotFoundException...
        lock = fos.getChannel().lock(); // ... and I won't acquire a lock.
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(value);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log it.
    } finally {
        // Close locks and I/O streams.
    }
```

The problem: if JVM1 is currently reading the file test.dat and JVM2 is trying to write to the same file then FileNotFoundException (*"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"*) will be thrown on JVM2 in "new FileOutputStream(new File("//share/test.dat"))" line.
It seems to be Catch22 case: on the one hand I want to acquire a lock to get I/O stream; on the other hand I need to have an I/O stream to acquire a lock.
As I could see, the same situation with RandomAccessFile.

Any ideas?..

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the error message, Windows just won't let you do what you're trying to do. You can treat the Windows error itself as the lock condition, if you think about it. You would have a cognate problem here anyway because of the timing window between the open and the lock. Windows in a way is doing you a favor here. For once.

Comment: Does it mean that Java's NIO file locking mechanism is useless in Windows? I.e. I'll never get a file lock if the file is currently reading/writing by another process.

Comment: @Lopotun It means that Windows already has a file locking mechanism for open files. You don't need two.

Comment: If so, it's a very important point. I've never seen it mentioned explicitly before. I wish I had more specific exception for this case. A general FileNotFoundException confuses.